# My data frame datatype is object. i need to convert it on float to make the seaborn and matplot plots

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is the data type of the columns of my dataframe. I need to convert these into type 'float':

```py
df.dtypes

Node_Name                                    object
Cell_id                                      object
CascadeID                                    object
RecordDate                                   object
Connection Drop Rate                         object
Connection Failure Rate                      object
DL Tonnage                                   object
UL Tonnage                                   object
Cell Availability (%)                        object
Inter Frequency Handover Success Rate (%)    object
Intra Frequency Handover Success Rate (%)    object
RRC Connection Attempts                      object
Avg Number of RRC Connected Users            object
dtype: object
```

Comment: it give me this error ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'null'

Comment: please comment on my answer so that I will get a notification of your response. I will not be able to know if you have typed something if you comment on your answer! I have edited my answer to cater for null values now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the datatype, do the following:

`df =df.astype('float')`

This will convert all the columns to type `float`.
If you want to convert only a particular column, do :

`df['column']=df['column'].astype('float')`

If you have null values in your column, you will have to replace them with another value (like -99999 or any other value that ***does not exist*** in that column). For example, say value `-9999` does not exist in `df['column']`. Then do the following:

```py
import numpy as np #required to convert values back to NaN

df['column'].fillna(-9999, inplace=True) #this will fill null values with -9999
df['column']=df['column'].astype('float') #convert column to float

df['column'].replace(-9999.0,np.nan,inplace=True) #convert all -9999 back to null.
```

This method will work for all columns having integer values in it.